# Finding an unbiased estimator for function of Poisson

Tags: statistics, self-learning, estimation

Let $X_1,...,X_n \sim Poi(\lambda)$ then unbiased estimator for $\lambda$ is obviously $\bar{X}$. What about $\tau(\lambda)=\sqrt{\lambda}$?
Also how would one derive UMVUE for this lambda?

Comment: Yes I got it wrong, I have fixed that now.